# Inserir quebra de linha com base no numero de caracteres evitando cortar as palavras

Tags: python, python-3.x, quebras-de-linha

Estou começando em Python e estou com dificuldade em algo relativamente simples o qual eu não estou conseguindo realizar, gostaria de adicionar uma quebra de linha em uma string a cada 13 caracteres sem cortar as palavras ao meio por exemplo:

```
'gosto de comer abacate'
```

se eu simplesmente adicionar o "\n" a cada 13 caracteres a frase sera cortada junto da palavra resultando em:

```
'gosto de come
r abacate'
```

gostaria de saber a forma de quebrar a linha sem cortar a palavra algo similar á:

```
'gosto de 
comer abacate'
```

Comment: Importante você [edit] sua pergunta e explicar de maneira objetiva e pontual a dificuldade encontrada, acompanhada de um [mcve] do problema e tentativa de solução. Para aproveitar melhor o site, entender e evitar fechamentos e negativações vale a pena ler o [Guia de sobrevivência do Stack Overflow em Português](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8045/70).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Como você disse que está começando por aqui vou fazer bem didático, mas você pode simplificar o meu código bem mais (por exemplo, começando a contagem em 0, como é o padrão da maioria das linguagens de programação e contando até 12).

Em resumo o que você deve fazer é analisar cada caractere contando a sua posição de 1 a 13. Assim, se chegar em 13 você deve quebrar a frase inserindo o `\n`, porém, somente se o próximo caractere for um espaço, indicando que estamos diante do final de uma palavra.

```
exemplo = 'gosto de comer abacate pra caramba meu deus que bom o abacate'

limite = 13
atual = 1
novaString = ''

for x in exemplo:
    atual += 1
    if atual >= 13 and x == ' ':
        novaString = novaString + '\n' 
        atual = 1
    else:
        novaString = novaString + x    

print(novaString)
```

Saída:

```
gosto de comer  
abacate pra  
caramba meu 
deus que bom 
o abacate
```